# Open SSL / Https url using selenium-rc

Tags: selenium, selenium2

**Please suggest me, how to open the SSL urls using selenium-rc?**
I face trouble while opening any https website through selenium RC in IE and FF browser both, as they prompt for accept the SSL certificate first.

Comment: smriti, it would be helpful for you to describe what you have attempted so far, and what went wrong with those attempts.

Comment: When I open selenium.open("https//xyz.com"); Its opens a popup for the accept security certificate.

Comment: smriti, I assume you are here because you are a tester or a software developer.  If that is true, you must have some experience logging bugs in a bug tracking system.  I suspect you have found it useful, when you log bugs or when you read others' bug reports, to include details about the bug's circumstances, e.g. the version of the software and the type and version of the browser, so that the bug can be reproduced.  Similarly, when you post questions like the one above to this forum, please try to include the same kind of details, because it will encourage people to help you.

Comment: This is a legitimate question, and a frequently asked question among Selenium users.  Nonetheless, I am downvoting it because I do not believe the OP put sufficient effort into researching it.  A Google search of "Selenium SSL" will reveal many articles about ways to deal with this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I will take this suggestion in logging my query in future. I have edited my query. Thanks again!+1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect your browser asks you to accept xyz.com's certificate because the certificate is self-signed.  There are ways to work around the problem, but they are browser-specific, and you did not mention which browser you used.

Some options for Firefox include:

- Configuring the browser to accept all certificates.  I do not recommend doing this unless your computer is only used for testing and is insulated from other machines in your network.
- Creating a custom profile for Firefox and instructing Selenium to launch Firefox with that profile.  A Google search will reveal many web pages about this approach, e.g. http://jktechtrip.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/selenium-and-self-signed-ssl-certificates-in-firefox-java-linux/.

Comment: Many Thanks for this help. The xyz.com is a just a example.  I have trouble on opening any https website through selenium RC in IE and FF browser both, as they prompt for accept the SSL certificate. 
This article helped me a lot …